# jQuery-ui Autocomplete display results wrong

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jQuery-ui autocomplete to create a search field with a remote data source. Everything works and I get results, however the results does not display in a list below the textfield like it is supposed to. The results are put in a list and gets displayed at the bottom of the page.
Here is my code:

```
<script>

$(function() {

$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
source: function(request,response)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?    >portfolios/ajax_clients_dropdown/"+request.term+".json?callback=ajax_clients_dropdown?",           
       // dataType: "text", 
        async: false,
        //jsonp: "callback",
        jsonpCallback: "ajax_clients_dropdown",
        success: function(data)
        {
          var fin = [];
          for(a=0;a<10;a++)
          {
            fin[a]= data[a].value;
          }

          console.log(fin);
          response(fin);
          console.log("success");
        },
        appendTo: "#autocomplete",
        position: {'my': 'left top', 'at': 'left top', 'of': '#autocomplete'},

        error: function(response){console.log("Fail");}

    });

}

});
}); 

</script>

<div class = "ui-widget" id="container">
<label for ="autocomplete">Clients</label>
<input id = "autocomplete" style ="" autocomplete = "on">
</div>
```

It doesn't matter weather I do the appendTo with #container or #autocomplete, it does nothing.

Here is the result that's supposed to be displayed:

```
["3434a62c bf592581", "a3ee7766 7894a7e0", "ea41d8ec 4e7df334", "919f6fac 96d4cdf0",     "24ecac17 bfbed443", "f0270fc4 a2659300", "ea803fac 94b43df4", "5337467f 1a41e158",     "fc54b844 0a19b69e", "a7393c7b aaea998b"]
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Why are you using `jsonpCallback: "ajax_clients_dropdown" ?

Comment: ajax_clients_dropdown is the name of the function in my controller that I'm calling. It worked when I put that in there, sadly I do not understand why it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This answer doesn't fix the problem, see comments for details.

Your `appendTo` and `position` properties have been assigned to the AJAX request, not to the autocomplete call. It's easier to see with the indentation fixed.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request,response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>portfolios/ajax_clients_dropdown/"+request.term+".json?callback=ajax_clients_dropdown?",           
                // dataType: "text", 
                async: false,
                //jsonp: "callback",
                jsonpCallback: "ajax_clients_dropdown",
                success: function(data) {
                    var fin = [];
                    for(a=0;a<10;a++)
                    {
                        fin[a]= data[a].value;
                    }
                    console.log(fin);
                    response(fin);
                    console.log("success");
                },
                error: function(response){console.log("Fail");}
            });
        },
        appendTo: "#autocomplete",
        position: {'my': 'left top', 'at': 'left top', 'of': '#autocomplete'}
    });
});
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, I didn't realize that is what I was doing. I changed it so that it looks like the code you posted. Sadly the problem is not fixed with this. All that happens is that the list moves from the bottom and slightly left of center, to the top left of the page.

Comment: Also, this only happened after I changed the #autocomplete to #container in both the appendTo and the position. When it is #autocomplete, nothing happens.

Comment: The web page is a cakephp baked one, and it is as if the autocomplete clashes with the cake. When the list are being displayed at the bottom, it gets displayed after the cake elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there might be a few issues here. If you just want the default behaviour for displaying, then you shouldn't need to mess with `appendTo` or `position`. Try the following:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request,response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>portfolios/ajax_clients_dropdown/"+request.term+".json?callback=ajax_clients_dropdown?",           
                // dataType: "text", 
                async: false,
                //jsonp: "callback",
                jsonpCallback: "ajax_clients_dropdown",
                success: function(data) {
                    var fin = [];
                    for(a=0;a<10;a++)
                    {
                        fin[a]= data[a].value;
                    }
                    console.log(fin);
                    response(fin);
                    console.log("success");
                },
                error: function(response){console.log("Fail");}
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>

<div class="ui-widget" id="container">
<label for="autocomplete">Clients</label>
<input id="autocomplete" style="" autocomplete="on">
</div>
```

Except for the data source, which you say is working, this should be the same as what I have [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q5vdonao/).

Comment: Perhaps there is an id clash on your page. Does it work if you replace autocomplete with some other name that won't clash?

Comment: Nope, I changed the id, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who have this issue, first make sure you go here:

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

And you are referencing the correct css and jquery files. Next, this was my issue in ASP.NET MVC 4. I created a bundle, using
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/core.css", .....
but when I referenced it in my layout page, instead of calling @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css") I was calling @Scripts.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css").

This caused

```
 <script src="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"></script>
```

to be inserted rather than

```
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

so for those of you running into this situation using MVC, that could be it, or you may just not be referencing the correct css and js files properly.